# Change text using javascript not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to change text to "saving ... " when a link clicked, then I use ajax, query resets to save the form. one i receive the request i need to change the text back to normal.

In Firefox the work fine, but in chrome the text get change once response received. There is a delay in changing the text.

See my code:

```js
function submitForm(frm, action) {
  var performAction = true;
  var isChange = false;
  document.getElementById('saveButton').innerHTML = 'processing....';
  freezeWindow();
  if ((document.getElementById("primaryIframe") != null) && (action == "Save")) {
    var frameId = 0;
    functionSaveIframes(frameId, isChange);
  } else {
    if (performAction == true) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('singlePage', 'false');
      window.open('www.google.com', '_self');
    }
  }
}

function functionSaveIframes (frameId,isChange) {

var iframes = {"0":"frame1","1":"frame2"};
var url = {"0":"/test/testPrimaryPostAction.do",
           "1":"/test/test2PrimaryPostAction.do"};

       var iframe = document.getElementById(iframes[frameId]);
       var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
       var form = doc.forms[0];
       var isEdited = doc.forms[0].isEdited.value;
       var formData = $(form).serializeArray();
       formData.push({name: 'fwdval', value: 'Save'});
       var myUrl = url[frameId];

       if(isEdited == 'true'){
       isChange=true;
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 async: false,
                 cache: false,
                 url:  myUrl,
                 data: formData,
                 success: function(data) {
                   doc.forms[0].isEdited.value = "false";
                   frameId = frameId + 1 ;
                   if (frameId < 9) {
                     functionSaveIframes(frameId,isChange);
                   }else if (frameId == 9){
                     reloadErrors(isChange);
                   }
                 },
                 error: function(e){
                      $("#freezeFrame").css("display","none");
                      alert("error Saving Data in " + iframes[frameId] + "Please try again");
                 }
            });
       }
       else{
            frameId = frameId + 1 ;
            if (frameId < 9) {
                functionSaveIframes(frameId,isChange);
            }
            else if (frameId == 9){
               reloadErrors(isChange);
            }
       }
    }
```

```html
<li><a id="saveButton" href="javascript:submitForm( document.forms[0], 'Save' );"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Anuradha it works fine for me..

Comment: There aren't any AJAX requests in the code you posted... Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry, i was unable to add functionSaveIframes() in eariler post. i have edited the code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**In Success Function you need to change text by using .html() **
Please check the below example.

Comment: Can you please share the example. here what i want to do is change the text to 'processing....'  once user click on the save. but the problem here is it is n't change to processing ... in chrome. it get change once the request receive the response. there is a delay when we add that ajax part

Comment: Updated code is working for me, Can you check in your system and let me know what type of error your getting...

Comment: I'm not getting error, there is a delay in chaning text. Save lable doen't change as soon as the link get click. it take time and change once we receive the response. This is not happen in fireforx. the problem is with chrome.